# Parameter passed by reference getting lost in OpenCV C++ class

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to call the following method in a C++ class, like so:

```
getMatches(m_queryDescriptors, m_matches); // at this point, m_queryDescriptors is populated as expected.
```

However, when I step through to the method:

```
void PatternDetector::getMatches(const cv::Mat& queryDescriptors, std::vector<cv::DMatch>& matches)
{
    matches.clear();
    if (enableRatioTest)
    {
        m_matcher->knnMatch(queryDescriptors, m_knnMatches, 2); //<-- At this point, 
                                                                // the queryDescriptors parameter seems to be 
                                                                // re-initialised with default empty values.
```

Could this be a simple syntax problem, or a wider OpenCV issue? Am I using inputArray incorrectly?

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Best,
Alias

Comment: There is usually no need to pass Mat objects by reference. Does the problem go away if you pass by value?

Comment: But you are talking about situation BEFORE knnMatch call ?

Comment: Anyway, the problem is not about passing by reference. It's even the other way round - generally (but nut in this situation) passing by value might cause you get object with not state you wanted and passing by reference it's nothing more than passing the same object! see http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html